# How can I use multiple statements in an Angular ES6 Observer function?

Tags: angular, observable, observers

The original convention is to do something like this

```
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
      next: products => {
        this.products = products
        this.filteredProducts = products
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
```

However when trying to use the ES6 shortcut below, I can't get the next function to handle multiple statements. If I use one statement, it works fine.

```
    //   next(products) {
    //     this.products = products
    //     this.filteredProducts = products},
    //   error(err) {this.errorMessage = err}
```

Is it possible to use write multiple lines here?

Comment: Are you wrapping the `next(){}, error(){}` inside curly braces to make it a single argument (an observer)?

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes, they are inside curly braces as an observer

Comment: similar to keith I can't replicate the issue [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-w3mavu)

Comment: can you clarify why you think `this.filteredProducts = products` isn't working (I suspect it is)

Comment: @AndrewAllen It works in my first block of code and I can see my products. When I try it in the second block of code, I can't see my products at all

Comment: When debugging, `this.products` always gets populated correctly. Yet for some reason, it won't display on the webpage when using the 2nd block of code

Comment: In the subscribe, change the callback parameter variable to "newProducts". Maybe the block variables are being mixed. So this.products = newProducts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using it should work.  Here's a stack that I created to verify..
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ug28l2

Comment: +1 for your answer. It seems to work with console logs , but it isn't working for my `this.filteredProducts = products` statement. I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `next:` and `error:`

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
            this.products = products
            this.filteredProducts = products
          },
          err => {
            this.errorMessage = err
          });
```